# Oracle SQL - how to insert multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

insert into table (col_identifier, period) values ('Proceeds', 2016)

I would like to insert for period 2016 to 2080. Is it possible to insert this range in one line statement, or do I have to write it out for each period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with a query that generates rows:

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( col_identifier, period )
  SELECT 'Proceeds', 2015 + LEVEL
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY 2015 + LEVEL <= 2080;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( col_identifier, period )
  WITH years ( year ) AS (
    SELECT 2016 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT year + 1 FROM years WHERE year < 2080
  )
  SELECT 'Proceeds', year
  FROM   years;
```

Comment: can you explain why you used "Level" and "Dual"?

Comment: Oracle documentation for the [`LEVEL` pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm#i1009261) and the [`DUAL` table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm)